# How to extract onChange method's String parameters using Regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have `select` elements as below

```
<select name="selectid1" id="selectid1" onChange="script.selectChange(this,'tr');">.......</select>
```

and

```
<select name="selectid2" id="selectid2" onChange="script.selectChange(this,'div');">.......</select>
```

I want to extract the `selectChange` method's String paramter (the 2nd paramter) `tr` and `div` of the `onChange` attribute of both the select elemets using regular expresssion.

I can get the value of `onChange` using

```
var selectid1 = $('#selectid1').attr('onChange'); //script.selectChange(this,'tr');
```

and

```
var selectid2 = $('#selectid2').attr('onChange'); //script.selectChange(this,'div');
```

What regex should I use in order to get strings `'tr'` and `'div'` from the variables?

Comment: May I know _why_ ?

Comment: What's the point of doing this exercise?

Comment: I am passing these regex extracted string for making generic appends in my project

For example
`$('selectid1').closest('tr').after('<input />');`

and in some cases

`$('select').closest('div').after('<input />');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just for test case - use the following approach with `String.match` function:

```
var selectid1 = "script.selectChange(this,'tr')",
    param = selectid1.match(/,\s?['"]([^)]+)['"]/)[1];

console.log(param);  // tr
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/onChange="script.selectChange\(this,'([^']*)'/g
```

Demo here --> https://regex101.com/r/uW2aQ6/1